# Directory with ACL - permission denied

Tags: centos, file-permissions, acl, redhat-classic

Please, tell me, how can give access to directory with ACL as in RedHat(or CentOS)? I must not disabled the ACL.

```
 ls -al /path    
 drwxrwxr-x+  9 bitrix bitrix  4096 Feb 14 18:10 .
 drwxrwxr-x+ 18 bitrix bitrix  4096 Feb 10 17:03 ..
-rw-rwx---+  1 bitrix bitrix    18 Oct 16  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-rwx---+  1 bitrix bitrix   176 Oct 16  2014 .bash_profile
-rw-rwx---+  1 bitrix bitrix   124 Oct 16  2014 .bashrc
```

User is in "bitrix" group. I set this directory as home for user, but:

```
 su user
bash: /path/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in Arch Linux but it should be more or less the same command.

## USING ACL:

```
sudo setfacl -R -d -m o::rwx /path/.bashrc
sudo setfacl -R -m o::rwx /path/.bashrc
```

Of course that's an uncesserilly long way of doing it

## Using chmod:

```
chmod +x /path/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't solved the problem

Comment: Thank you, it is the solution. I gave "chmod +x" to parent directory.